# Python import error, when including a c++ extension

Tags: python, c++, linker

In python, I use extension to wrap my C++ code and to use it in python. I can compile and link my code. However once I import the resulting module 'example' in python

```
import example
```

I get the following error. (I replaced the path to the module by "path")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<path>/example.py", line 28, in <module>
_example = swig_import_helper()
  File "/<path>/example.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_example', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/<otherpath>/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: dlopen(/<path>/_example.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost4math12sph_hankel_1IiiEESt7complexINS0_6detail13bessel_traitsIT_T0_NS0_8policies6policyINS7_14default_policyES9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_S9_EEE11result_typeEES5_S6_
  Referenced from: /<path>/_example.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to link against another library? It looks like you might be trying to use a boost math library.

Comment: Yes that is indeed the case. Which options do I have to set in order to link against the library?

Comment: If you are using GCC, you would normally pass something like -lname for a library named libname.so.